# Which IPv4 is used while running ping *hostname* command

Tags: network-programming

If I have a hostname that has several IPv4 addresses assigned.

Which IPv4 will be used by ping request to resolve the hostname address [for example, while running "ping Some-Pc"]?

Comment: Depends on routes and gateways to that address.

Comment: @yogur can you please provide me some information \ a link?

Comment: What do you mean by 'which IPv4'? There is only one IPv4. It is the name of a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command 'route' in Linux and you will see the routing tables. Based on the destination address and the routing table you should be able to determine the interface being used to send the ICMP messages and thus the src IP address.

For example, given this routing table in Linux:

```
[mynode]$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         gateway         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
10.0.2.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s3
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.56.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp0s8
192.168.124.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

If you send a ping to address 10.0.2.45, it will use enp0s3 and the corresponding IP address as src address.
If you send a ping to address 172.17.0.0 it will send the address from NIC docker0 and the corresponding src IP address.

With *ifconfig* in Linux (*ipconfig* in Windows) you can see the IP address assigned to each interface.